# Bing's house with two rooms: an attempt for an explicit deformation retraction and a question on homotopy type

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

In the first pages of his "Algebraic Topology" book, Allen Hatcher describes a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$, a box divided horizontally by a rectangle in two chambers, where the south chamber is accessible by a vertical tunnel (in green in the picture) obtained punching down a square from the ceiling of the north chamber, while viceversa the north chamber is accessible by a similar tunnel dug from the bottom of the box. Also, two vertical rectangles (in pink) are inserted as support walls as shown in the figure below:

[image: A house with two rooms]

Such space (we call it $X$) is contractible, and the author proves it in the following way (here $\simeq$ means homotopy equivalent and $=$ homeomorphic):

> To see that $X$ is contractible, consider a closed $\epsilon$ neighborhood $N(X)$ of $X$.
> This clearly deformation retracts onto $X$ if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. In fact, $N(X)$ is the mapping cylinder of a map from the boundary surface of $N(X)$ to $X$. Less obvious is the fact that $N(X)$ is homeomorphic to $D^3$, the unit ball in $\mathbb{R^3}$. To see this, imagine forming $N(X)$ from a ball of clay by pushing a finger into the ball to create the upper tunnel, then gradually hollowing out the lower chamber, and similarly pushing a finger in to create the lower tunnel and hollowing out the upper chamber.
> Mathematically, this process gives a family of embeddings $h_t: D^3 \to \mathbb{R^3}$ starting with the usual inclusion $D^3 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ and ending with a homeomorphism onto $N(X)$.
> Thus we have $X \simeq N(X) = D3 \simeq point$ , so $X$ is contractible since homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation. In fact, $X$ deformation retracts to a point. **For if $f_t$ is a deformation retraction of the ball $N(X)$ to a point $x_0 \in X$ and if $r : N(X) \to X$ is a retraction, for example the end result of a deformation retraction of $N(X)$ to $X$ , then the restriction of the composition $r f_t$ to $X$ is a deformation retraction of $X$ to $x_0$.**

With the help of a computer simulation, this [link](https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/the-deformation-retraction-of-bings-house/) and some imagination, I think I might figure out a possible deformation retraction (towards the center of the box) for $N(X)$ (the "tick" box surrounding $X$):

(1) Let take a first deformation retraction $f_1$ of the "tick" $\epsilon$ wall of $N(X)$ surrounding the rectangle $P1-P2-P3-P4$ that brings the segment $P4-P3$ onto $P1-P2$, leaving the faces of the vertical wall intact and digging a fissure in the middle of it, without tearing off the bottom of the wall below the segment $P1-P2$.

(2) Let's do a second deformation retraction $f_2$ on the same volume but now in the horizontal direction, so that point $P1$ is brought onto $P2$.

(3) Let's operate a third deformation retraction $f_3$ that now starts from the neighborhood of $P2$ and hollows a hole in the rigth wall of $N(X)$ towards the bottom, eventually developing a "free edge" from where the box can further collapse.

The same deformation retractions can happen on the other side of the box (for central simmetry) and from this point on what is left of $N(X)$ has some free faces enabling it to collapse on the central point.

*First question then: is this sequence $f_1 \to f_2 \to f_3$ a correct deformation retraction for $N(X)$?*

Here is my second matter.
When it comes to consider, as suggested by the author, the composition $r \dot (f_1 \to f_2 \to f_3)$ restricted to $X$, I notice that during $f_1$ nothing happens to the structure of $X$, apart from $P3$ moving towards $P2$ and $P4$ moving towards $P1$, while portions of the ceiling in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $P4 - P3$ are mapped continously on the vertical pink wall.
A similar behaviour appears during $f_2$, while $P1$ moves towards $P2$, but the vertical wall stays intact (at the end of $f_2$, we have that all the four points $P1, P2, P3, P4$ coincide, while the vertical wall is still intact and "made of" the images of points of $X$ belonging to the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the rectangle).
When $f_3$ finally starts, and the point $P2$ moves towards the bottom, a growing hole is produced in the external wall of $N(X)$, however the restriction to $X$ of the composition of such reformation retraction with $r$ produces a "hole" in the external wall of $X$ as well! Growing portions of the green segment to which $P1$ initially was belonging to are mapped (seemingly continously, as far as I can tell) on the border of the hole that is being produced in the external wall of $X$.

*I'm not sure that the transformation I am describing is a correct homotopy, but if so, being it a deformation retraction of $X$ how can it be that a "hole" is produced in the external wall? Would not this imply that the homotopy type of the retracting space is changing? Where am I wrong?*

Apologies for the long winded question, but I hope my points were clear and not too terribly distant from a rigorous approach.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you figure it out? I'm trying to understand the deformation retraction on Bing's house(the house with two rooms) too. And I am following the link provided in your questions too. It almost provided all informations but I think maybe I can share some thoughts after I read its description.

The first key point is to deform a hole in the wall. As you said, the thick version of the space is much easier to manupulate. But in order to squash out a hole, we dont need to retain to the original space. **We just need to only make the wall around the disks that make the two room(here rectangle P1,P2,P3,P4 in your question) thicker**. Here I use a simple anologue space to show how the more detailed idea. $Y$ is a space abtained by attaching a vertical segment and then a horizontal segment to a rectangle, simpified anologue to the subspace surrounding P1,P2,P3,P4 in the original question. And $X$ is its thicker version that only make the vertical segment thicker. Obviously $Y$ deformation retracts to $X$ by applying the canonical deformation retraction from $I \times I$ to $I \times \{0\} \cup \partial I \times I$. In the following content I will show how to squash out a hole in this simple anologue:

[image]

It's easy to see that we can squash out the thicker vertical line in $X$. Let's denote this deformation retract be $H: X\times I \rightarrow X$. And the retract from $X$ to $Y$ be $r: X \rightarrow Y$. As hatcher said, $r \circ H$ is a deformation retract of $Y$. Here $r$ is in fact the projection from left side and right side of the thick vertical line of $X$.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMOdB.png]

Let's imagine what will $r \circ H$ be like. First of all, the vertical line of $Y$ will be squashed to a point. Consider some point $a$ in the horizontal line of $Y$, at some $t \in I$, $H_t$ maps it to a point in the thick line of $X$, and then $r$ maps it back to maybe the horizontal line or vertical line of $Y$. As $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$, its image $r(H_t(a))$ goes right and down, and at some point goes beyonds the image of the cross point of the vertical and horizontal line of $Y$, and then goes beyond the cross point of the horizontal line of $Y$ and the bottom rectangle and goes to the left part in the bottom rectangle.

[image]

And at the time $t=1$, the operation part in fact is liked double covered: line b-c squashed to a point. a-b maped to $d-c$. And yet there still is a line covers the whole operation part:

[image]

This operation should be the keypoint for squashing out a hole. We just needs to squash down green line, purple point, and yellow line down.

[image]

Back to the original case, it's similar: we pull down to do a two fold map, squashing the disk. It's quite hard to draw. I am sorry to have it left for imagination(the picture is borrowed from the linked you provided). After this deformation retract, only a small part can already covered the disk and the cylinder surface. All other parts are moved down. It makes squash out the hole possible.

[image]

And for the homotopy type, it's possible that it changed during the during the deformation retraction, $H: X \times I \rightarrow X$ is a deformation retraction does not mean that $H: X \times [0, t] \rightarrow X$ is also a deformation retraction, as said in comments in the link:

> I think the thing that people intuitively expect in a deformation retract from a space X to some subspace, call it f_t from X to X, is that the homotopy type of the image f_t(X) will be constant with respect to t. There’s no reason for the homotopy type of f_t(X) to be fixed, since f_t(X) is just a continuous image of X. In the example contraction of Bing’s house that you give, the homotopy type of f_t(X) clearly changes. I suspect this is necessary for any contraction of Bing’s house, and part of the reason that this contraction is so hard to see.

And in the [link](https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/the-deformation-retraction-of-bings-house/), it also provides lots of [image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sketchesoftopology/4644072570/) to make the latter part of the deformation retract. It should be easier for figuring out the hole.

Sorry for the poor drawing. I Hopes that I expressed the thoughts for the deformation retract.

Comment: many thanks for this! I have to be honest here, I thought I had understood it but your question reopened a problem to be. this is good! it means I did not get it the first time. I have more doubts than before, now:) 
let me tell you the first one. with reference to your example spaces X and Y, what if instead of $H$ we take a deformation retract $H'$ of $X$ which squashes the vertical wall up to the bottom of the picture, entering the rectangle leaving just a segment to connect the two sides? now I have again that the restriction to $Y$ of $r \circ H'$ should be a deformation retract of $Y$.

Comment: ... I tried to draw it many times, but it seems to me that $r \circ H'$ ends up creating a hole in the space $Y$. this is clearly not possible, as if one space is a deformation retract of another one, the two spaces must be homotopy equivalent, which would not be the case. where am I wrong here?

Comment: ok, I think I finally got it. $r \circ H'$ is not a deformation retraction as it it not $=$ to the identity in the set $r \circ H'_1(Y)$. I think in the Hatcher example this works because he talks about a deformation retraction of a _point_ $x_o \in X$ (here X is the set in his example) and restricted to $x_o$ the composition is the identity. so this is not automatic, but we have to verify if the final composition is still a retraction, which may not always be the case....

Comment: I have another comment, though. Whilst I appreciate that the homotopy type can change during the deformation retraction, I am not sure of two things
1. the hole that appears in the house may not be the hint that the homotopy type has changed, precisely because the whole set will later contract to a point. not every "hole" is responsible for non contractibility, see for instance a sphere with a point removed that happily contracts to a point.

Comment: 2. looking at how Hatcher proves contractibility, not only a ball can deformation retract to a point, but it can also deformation retract to _any_ ball contained in it. This means that if we deformation retract a ball to a ball, say, half of its radius, the image of this reduced ball under the embedding $h$ should still be a deformation retract of $N(X)$... I am not sure if the image of the "thin" space is still the same at this point, but it should still have the homotopy type of a point... thoughts?

Comment: @l4teLearner you are right. $r \circ H^{\prime}$ is not a deformation retraction. And I am not quite understand your question 1 and 2. So I cannot answer it and in fact I'am a newbie reading Hatcher's book too haha. Maybe you can ask a new question for it sometime later and linked to this problem. And I suggest reading section 4, "retraction and deformation" in the book Algebraic Topology by Spanier too. He distinguishes lots of subtle concepts related to deformation retract, like weak deformation retract/deformation retract/strong deformation retract(the definition in hatcher's book).

Comment: for you second question. maybe it's related to the defintion of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_(topology). Bing's house is an example for being contractible but not collapsible. Maybe our intuition is more like the defition for collapsible

Comment: I now realize that Hatcher never described the way in which   $N(X)$ retracts to a point. What was implicit in my description is a depiction of the retraction in the following way: let's look at a ball of radius $R$ as composed by 2-dimensional spheres of radius ranging continously from $0$ to $R$. When applying the homeomorphism from the ball to $N(X)$ each sphere will map homeomorphically to a "shell" of $N(X)$. So, as the ball retracts from a sphere of radius $R$ to its center, $N(X)$ will retract accordingly. If we call $h$ the homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R^3}$ to itself ...

Comment: ... that maps the ball $D_3$ to $N(X)$, and call $D(\rho)$ the ball of radius $\rho$, we have that $h(D(R))=N(X)$ and that $h(D(t))$ describes a deformation retraction of $N(X)$ when $t$ ranges from $R$ to $0$. This is the computer simulation I attempted that suggested how the wall of my initial question could be squashed (but went nuts when the "hole" appeared). If you think about it, you can also think to a deformation retraction of to a given radius $\rho<R$ but $>0$. It would.be a different trasformation but its image $h(D(\rho))$ will coincide with some step of the deformation retraction

Comment: ... of $N(X)$ and so will still be homotopy equivalent to $N(X)$. For this reason I am not fully convinced that a deformation retraction to a point of Bing's house has to necessary change the homotopy type of its image when $t$ is varying. Hope I clarified my point now. cheers